# How does Blender know what color is the background color for a texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

You can add multiple texture slots in texture paint mode, to act as a sort of 'layers'. You then add all of them with their own texture node and combine the 'layers' with MixRGB nodes.

But, you can create textures with different background colors and somehow Blender knows for each of the textures what that color is and to treat it as 'transparent' when blending the texture layers. How does it know that color?

Comment: When you create a new texture using the *Texture* tab in the Properties Panel, in the "New Image" settings box that pops up, one of the available options is "Color.*

Comment: Ah I thought that was just what was used to do the initial fill, but it makes sense when you think about it. Thanks.